# Procedure to give the site URL name instead of localhost:port

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, url

We want to give our existing site URL a name instead of `http://pcname:port`, we would want to have something like `http://speedsolutions`

Also, for the new sites that we would be creating we need to create their URL as `http://somename` instead of localhost:port.

We have browsed through articles but not sure which one to try out. Has anyone done this before, please share the method. Is the concept of host header used for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what your talking about is alternate access mapping (aam):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288609(v=office.12).aspx

step by step guide with images:

http://www.1ask2.com/sharepoint/AlternateAccessMapping.html

**EDIT**

in your case localhost is not nice to use so you would need to change the aam and iis settings! its quite easy! follow:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/02/27/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

the main part for you is the iss binding! it also talks about aam.

Comment: this link shows images for SP2007, do you have any reference for SP2010 or SP2013?

Comment: for 2013 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(v=office.15).aspx and 2010 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it refers to planning and I would like to get the procedure guide to implement it, if someone has already done it please post.

Comment: just ammended answer

Comment: sorry to mention localhost; it is http://pcname:port instead... I have updated the question./

Comment: yes when you create the webapplication that would be the default name and unique port number! my updated answer will solve your issue!